# Is it legal and good practice to leave methods unimplemented?

Tags: c++, virtual

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
public:
  virtual void taunt() = 0;
  virtual void hide() = 0;
};

template <int nx, int ny>
class derivedA : public base
{
  void hide();
public:
  void taunt() { cout << "derivedA" << endl; }

  char c[nx][ny];
};

template <int nx, int ny, int nz>
class derivedB : public base
{
  void taunt();
public:

  void hide() { cout << "hide B" << end; }
  char c[nx][ny][nz];
};

int main()
{
  derived * dp = new derivedA();

  dp->taunt();

  delete dp;

  DerivedB b;

  dp = &b;

  dp->hide();

  return 0;
}
```

A and B are both derived from the pure virtual class base, and both have one method unimplemented. Is it legal to leave one method unimplemented? Is it acceptable or good practice to leave one method unimplemented? Are there better ways?

Edit:
I just noticed that the classes are not derived from base. I've changed the code so that it does.

Comment: *"A and B are both derived from the pure virtual class base"* -- No, they're not.  They're both baseless.

Comment: You can not instantiate a class with even a single method unimiplemented. Just try it on random compiler and you will see the compilation error.

Comment: `derived * dp = new derivedA();` : `derived` is not a type and `derivedA()` is illegal: `derivedA<4, 5>()`.

Comment: Saying or wishing your classes are derived from some base class doesn't make it so. You need to specify the base class(es) as `class derivedA : public base { ... };` Do that and try compiling your code on any compiler, you'll answer your questions yourself.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: Not true.  You can instantiate a class with unimplemented methods as long as you don't try to call those methods.  This is often done with copy constructors to make classes non-copyable.  What you can't instantiate is classes with pure virtual functions.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley really? Maybe I am confused then It is a good thing I posted this as comment not as answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No, because Derived has a pure virtual function, bar.

Comment: user52343, you have what appear to me to be three correct answers all of which completely answer your question (the answer is: yes, it's fine to have such classes but you can't instantiate them directly, and the compiler will enforce this); you should either accept one of them or make it clearer what your question is so that someone can actually answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you derive from a class that has a pure virtual method and you don't override that method in the derived class, that derived class will be an abstract class as well.  If this is OK for you (e.g. you will derive it further), than you can do that.  If you *do* want to instantiate that derived class, than you will have to override all pure abstract methods

Note that in your example you do not derive from the abstract `base` class: both `derivedA` and `derivedB` are standalone classes.  You need:

```
class derivedA : public base {
  //...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to instantiate any class that has pure virtual member functions. You can of course *have* such a class, but any instances of it must be of subclasses in which all the pure virtuals have been given definitions.